# SQL date format: dd/mm/yyyy hh:ss

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have been trying to find a date format: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm.

I am using convert (varchar, rc.CreatedDateTime, ???). 131 is not what i need either.

I seem to be able to find an awful lot that are very close, but not this particular one, am I missing something glaringly obvious or is there another function I can use??

Comment: hh:ss? You don't care about minutes? And why do you want to use a regional format? So you can be sure American and other viewers will be completely confused? Why not use an unambiguous output format like `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Comment: It is a private report for a business, so it's as regional as it gets...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this, just replace the `getdate()` with your field:

```
select convert(char(10), getdate(), 103) + ' ' 
    + convert(char(8), getdate(), 108)
```

which gives you the results:

```
14/03/2012 17:05:47
```

If you just want the hour and seconds then:

```
select convert(char(10), getdate(), 103) + ' ' 
    + Left(convert(char(8), getdate(), 108), 2) + ':'
    + Right(convert(char(8), getdate(), 108), 2)
```

Here is a helpful link with date/time conversions:

http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Based on your comment that it should be `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` then the query would be:

```
select convert(char(10), getdate(), 103) + ' ' 
    + Left(convert(char(8), getdate(), 108), 5)
```

OR without the `LEFT()`

```
select convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 103) + ' ' 
    + convert(char(5), getdate(), 108)
```

Comment: @dann.dev no problem the link is very handy to keep bookmarked.  I use it all the time.

Comment: Why varchar though? Do you expect anything other than the number of characters defined? And why `LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ...), 5)`? Why not just `CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), ...)`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I typically use varchar on my date conversions but I see your point. I adjusted the queries to use char and shortened the lengths from 8 to 2,5 respectively.  thanks for pointing that out.  As far as the last LEFT that I had, it was showing that you can return just the 5 characters of the time.

Comment: Well two things still wrong IMHO. The first `LEFT(CONVERT(CHAR(2), ...), 2)` could still be `CONVERT(CHAR(2), ...)` the left is redundant. And the `RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(2), ...), 2)`, you should try that.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I put the Left/Right back to char(8) so it will get the correct values if he was looking for hh:ss which is what was originally posted as the question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you need dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm not dd/mm/yyyy hh:ss

```
SELECT convert (varchar(10), rc.CreatedDateTime, 103) + ' ' + 
       convert(varchar(5), rc.CreatedDateTime, 108)
```

Comment: Why varchar? The length is always going to be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), rc.CreatedDateTime, 103) + ' ' 
     + CONVERT(CHAR(5),  rc.CreatedDateTime, 108)
FROM dbo.[table_name];
```